# Event handlers inside SSR documents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, eventhandler, server-side-rendering

I asked some questions relating to NextJS and SSR on Stack Overflow and got good answers, but I'm left with one burning question, which is why one can't put event handlers in SSR code.  Perhaps this is specific to one thing in the NextJS world (the documentation wasn't clear).  Or is this a general aspect of SSR (that one can't put event handlers in SSR code)?

Specifically, in NextJS and they have a sort of 'generic' document -- into which you can put some of your HTML code -- called _document (https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-document) that is only rendered on the server.  In a comment, they say

```
/ _document is only rendered on the server side and not on the client side
// Event handlers like onClick can't be added to this file
```

Why can't one add event handlers to documents rendered on the server?  A contributor on Stack Overflow said it was because this code is 'run' on the server.  What does this mean?  It's not PHP or Node, right, it's not actually *executing* on the server, is it? Doesn't SSR just mean that the code is converted from its React implementation (in the case of NextJS) to HTML and then that HTML is sent via a HTTP request to the browser, which processes it there?  So any event handlers wouldn't actually come into play until the code reaches the browser?

Is it that for SSR code the browser *can't* attach event handlers to the HTML in some manner?

I'm clearly missing an obvious point, so I'd welcome being steered in the right direction.  Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: You can add event handlers on react SSR components as long as you properly `hydrate` them on the client-side

Comment: @apokryfos.  Thanks -- what does `hydrate` mean in this context?  How might I do it? (I'm a beginner with NextJS and SSR).

Comment: I've not used NextJS but React server has [hydrate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate) which basically transfers control of elements rendered by react server to React on the client side. I suspect that in the background NextJS will use the same or something similar